# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when trying to access url

Tags: javascript, express, http, socket.io, discord

so I'm having a weird error. I'm doing communication via socket.io, but I'm getting this error. It is important to say that this error only happens the second time I access the url, the first time it works normally. can anybody help me? I've tried to see other questions about this error, but none of them solved my problem.

Client (express-server)

```js
const router = require('express').Router()
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const config = require('../../../config.json')
const io = require('socket.io-client')
const socket = io(config.boturl, {query:`socketpass=${config.socketpass}`})
    
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    socket.emit('getBotClient')
    socket.on('botClient', data => {
        res.send(data)
        return
    })
})
module.exports = router
```

Server (Discord bot)

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(5556)
const config = require('../config.json')
module.exports = (client) => {
    try {
        try {
            io.use((socket, next) => { //validate that only the socket with the correct password can connect
                try {
                    const request = socket.request;
                    const address = socket.handshake.address;
                    console.log('\x1b[33m(' + Date.now() + ') connected to: ' + address + '...\x1b[0m');
                    if (request._query['socketpass'] != config.socketpass) {
                        console.log(`\x1b[31m(${Date.now()}) Connection denied! socketpass fornecido: ${request._query['socketpass']}\x1b[0m`)
                        return
                    }
                    if (request._query['socketpass'] === config.socketpass) { // This if is just a guarantee that the password is really correct
                        console.log(`\x1b[32m(${Date.now()}) Connection accepted!\x1b[0m`)
                        next();
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(`\x1b[31m(${Date.now()}) Error!\x1b[0m`)
                    console.log(e)
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`(${Date.now()}) Error!`)
            console.log(e)
        }
        try {
            io.on('connection', socket => {
                socket.on('getBotClient', data => {
                    return socket.emit('botClient', client)
                })
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`(${Date.now()}) Error`)
            console.log(e)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`error: ${Date.now()}`)
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting `socket.on('botClient', data => {...})` inside of `router.get()` is a problem.  That means you're adding a new listener for the `botClient` message every time the `/` route gets requested and those listeners never go away so they pile up, leading to duplicate responses.  It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish to know what to suggest instead, but the current code is clearly wrong in that way.

Comment: In addition to what @jfriend00, that code also keeps calling `send()` every time `botClient` gets emitted, and you should only call `send()` once per HTTP request. This causes the issue. Why do you even have a HTTP server, it does almost nothing?